# I have two realtive layouts , one over the other .But keyboard of one layout is pushing the other layout out of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two Relative layouts. Such that , one is over the other .

```
<RelativeLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"


    tools:context="com.mettl.zobbr.SliderActivity" >

     <RelativeLayout 
         android:id="@+id/dddd"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:isScrollContainer="false" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >




     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Button06"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="false" 


        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/spin_title" />


      <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
       android:background="#00000000"
       android:isScrollContainer="false" 
       android:onClick="BackToJob"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
         android:background="#00000000"
         android:isScrollContainer="false" 
       android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="BackToLoc"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

     <ScrollView 

         android:layout_below="@+id/dddd"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/spin_back"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >

    <RelativeLayout 
         android:layout_below="@+id/dddd"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     >




      <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/hour"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"


             android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:layout_width="75dp"/>

       <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/second"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"

              android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/hour"

            android:layout_width="75dp"/>


         <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView124"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dp"

       android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:paddingTop="65dp"
        android:text="000/-" />




           <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textView1234"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dp"

        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:inputType="number"

        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_below="@+id/hour"

         android:paddingTop="95dp"
         />







</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>


     <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/btnLL"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:onClick="refresh"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
         android:background="@drawable/veri_button"/>
    <Button 
       android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background_selector"
         />


  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But when I click on the edit text of the second layout . The softKeyboard pushes the the first layout out of the screen .(The first layout ,is located on top of the screen ).

I have used `android:isScrollContainer="false"` ,yet the required result was not achieved.
I have added `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to the manifest as well . Still did not work.

Comment: remove that tag android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" from manifest. 
it will work for sure. just checked it.

Comment: I have made that change . But the same error is reoccurring .

Answer (score 0):

try in your manifest instead of:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

use:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

Comment: That  stopped the upper layout from being pushed up . But now the lower layout is not being pushed up . The softKeyBoard ,is hiding the EditextView .What I want to do is to ,only scroll up the lower view to view the text  . But the upper view remains unaltered.

Comment: If you want this sort of effect would a scrollview for your layouts be of more use

Comment: Okay , I'm not sure if m doing it right . I have added the second relative view inside a scrollView . But the same problem still remains . I have edited the question , with the new layout.